# Apagar arquivos de logs com data posterior a uma semana utilizando log4j

Tags: java, log4j, logging

Na minha aplicação utilizo a biblioteca log4j para gerar os logs de todo o sistema. Está funcionando corretamente, utilizo as seguintes configurações:

## Direct log messages to a log file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log/aplicacao.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss:SSS},%t,,%-5p,%c{1}:%L-%m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=50KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxHistory=2

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma propriedade que faça apagar os arquivos velhos que já tenham mais de uma semana, pois se meu sistema ficar rodando por muito tempo é inviável que ocupe muita memória, pois a aplicação que estou desenvolvido é para ser utilizado em máquinas bem antigas.

Existe alguma solução para isso? Adicionei as propriedade MaxFileSize e MaxHistory e a mesma não funcinou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solução #1 - Mude para `RollingFileAppender`

A classe `RollingFileAppender` possui o atributo `MaxBackupIndex`, que faz exatamente o que você precisa, isto é, limitar o histórico de logs a um certo número.

Exemplo:

```
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=7
```

Entretanto, o `DailyRollingFileAppender` não possui este atributo. Uma solução seria trocar o tipo de log.

## Solução #2 - Utilize uma implementação própria

Se precisar mesmo manter o `DaylyRollingFileAppender` é possível criar sua próxima implementação do `FileAppender`. Encontrei dois links que ensinam a fazer isso:

- [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender)
- [Improving the Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender](http://blog.kimb3r.com/2008/07/improving-log4j-dailyrollingfileappende.html)

Note que não cheguei a testar as soluções acima.

## Solução #3 - Faça a limpeza num script agendado no Sistema Operacional

Uma última alternativa é agendar (*cron*) a limpeza diária dos logs antigos. [Nesta questão do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683364/how-to-configure-log4j-to-only-keep-log-files-for-the-last-seven-days) encontrei um comando que você poderia usar:

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Utilize o DailyRollingFileAppender e fiz uma implementação própria. Obrigado @utluiz